# powershell: Changing start type of services on a windows 7 machine

Tags: windows, powershell, service

Ive wrote a script to get the services of a machine and i want to mirror the StartMode to another machine.  I cant think of how to achieve the latter: setting the services on the remote machine.  Heres a script ive written so far:

```
#List of Issue of services 
$NamesOfIssueServices = "Browser", "Dhcp", "Dnscache", "dwmrcs", "iphlpsvc", "LanmanServer", "LanmanWorkstation", "MMCSS", "MpsSvc", "Netlogon", "Netman", "netprofm", "NlaSvc", "nsi", "p2pimsvc","PNRPsvc","PolicyAgent", "SessionEnv", "stisvc", "W32Time", "WinHttpAutoProxySvc", "WinRM"

#get all services 
$W32Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service

#filter wanted services 
$IssueServices = $W32Services | Where-Object {$NamesOfIssueServices -contains $_.name}

#display wanted services
$IssueServices | Sort-Object name | ft Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, StartName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell v2.0 you can easily do that by using the [Set-Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315324.aspx) cmdlet:

```
foreach ($service in $issueServices) {
    $startMode = $service.StartMode

    if ($service.StartMode -eq "Auto") {
        $startMode = "Automatic"
    } 

    Set-Service -ComputerName TheRemoteMachine -Name $service.Name -StartupType $startMode
}
```

The conditional statement is due to an *incompatibility* between the value `"Auto"` obtained from the `StartMode` property and the argument `"Automatic"` expected by the `-StartupType` parameter.

Comment: +1 for having saw the difference from AUTO in win32_service and AUTOMATIC in set-service!